# Map my menu key to fn or achieve similar functionality

Tags: keyboard, volume-control, function-keys, shortcut-keys

I'm using an Lenovo Ideapad y410p and (hoping someone at Lenovo sees this) for some stupid reason, Lenovo decided to put the Fn key on the left side of the keyboard while most of the keys with extra functions bound to them are on the right side of the keyboard.

My main issue with this is that I can't adjust the volume with one hand. I need to use left hand to hold the Fn key and right hand to arrow left or right (up/down for brightness).

Now I've done my research on using xmodmap and xev to remap keys. And I've also done enough research to know that xev cannot pick up the Fn key and it cannot be remapped.

All I could find was people hoping to make their Fn key do something else and they were left SOL. I actually want to do the opposite and bind another key (specifically my menu key which mirrors the Fn key on the right side of the keyboard) to do the same as Fn.

Right now I have to press:

Fn + Left Arrow - volume down
Fn + Right Arrow - volume up
Fn + Up Arrow - brightness up
Fn + Down Arrow - brightness down

And I would like be able to do the following:

Menu + Left Arrow - volume down
Menu + Right Arrow - volume up
Menu + Up Arrow - brightness up
Menu + Down Arrow - brightness down

Preferably I would like to be able to do this while still leaving the Fn commands in tact, but I could live without it. I could also live without changing brightness, it is not as important to me as being able to adjust volume with one hand.

In the system settings and keyboard shortcuts I could see how to rebind volume up from "audio volume up" (which is Fn + Right Arrow) to another key, but it binds after a single key and won't seem to let me do key combinations. This is the closest I have come to figure it out.

The most ideal situation would be to make the Menu key do what the Fn key does. I'm doubting this is possible so I would just like to set up a shortcut where 'Menu + Left Arrow' turns volume down and 'Menu + Right Arrow' does turns volume up.

Just to clarify, the Menu key is a key I have between my alt and ctrl on the right side of the keyboard, it makes context menus appear when pressed. Its keycode is 135 and its action is Menu.

Thanks for reading. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add what release & which desktop you are using?